# Do functions execute loops when called?

Tags: c#, function, loops

I'm trying to write a program that consists of some items (only 2 of them for now). It doesn't show any errors in the console, but when I try to call the Main function more than once, it doesn't execute the loops inside. Here's the code by the way.

```
 public static class Program
{

    public static string input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    public static int health = 100;
    public static int energy = 100;
    

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a game used for testing items");
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to use items or get them? (Typing in status shows the value of your health and energy)");
        if (Program.input == "get")
        {
            Items.GetItems();
        }

        if (Program.input == "use")
        {
            ItemUser();
        }

        if (Program.input == "status")
        {
            StatusChecker();
        }

    }
    public static void StatusChecker()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Your health is " + Program.health);
        Console.WriteLine("Your energy is " + Program.energy);
    }
    public static void ItemUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What do you want to use?");
        string useChecker = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        if (useChecker == "healthPotion")
          {
            health += 100;
            Items.healthPotion--;
          }
        if (useChecker == "energyDrink")
           {
            energy += 100;
            Items.energyDrink--;
           }

    }
}
public static class Items
{
    public static int healthPotion = 0;
    public static int energyDrink = 0;
    public static void GetItems()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        string itemChecker = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        if ( itemChecker == "health potion")
        {
            healthPotion++;
            Program.Main();
        }
        if (itemChecker == "energy drink")
        {
            energyDrink++;
            Program.Main();
        }

    
    }
```

So I wanted the program to get the values after updating them, but it just stops after I call Main method more than once. Can anyone help me?
(I'm not that great at coding so I couldn't make really efficient code)

Comment: You don't have any loops, just conditionals.  How are you executing the program?

Comment: There is no "special treatment" of functions whether they contain loops or not. And your functions don't contain loops.

Comment: You have no loop, so you need to present your actual goal so people can help you. Furthermore `main()` represents your program; there is no reading/writing of data from outside, your data is hardcoded in your program, hence every time you call your program you just restart it from scratch, ie with the same results !

Comment: [Review] avoid putting user input ReadLine()) to set your static input field. Move the line [ input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()); ] to the Main() procedure and see what happens with rhe result of GetItems()

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any loops inside your `Main` method and every time you run the application you start from scratch and each of your variables contain initial values. If I get right what you're trying to achieve, I would suggest you to write the `Main` method like this to have loop which will ask a user for a command until the user enters `"quit"`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a game used for testing items");
        
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to use items or get them? (Typing in status shows the value of your health and energy)");
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userAnswer == "quit") break;

            if (userAnswer == "get")
            {
                Items.GetItems();
            }

            if (userAnswer == "use")
            {
                ItemUser();
            }

            if (userAnswer == "status")
            {
                StatusChecker();
            }
        }
    }
```

I noticed also that when you call `ItemUser` method you update static variables of your `Items` class, but in the `StatusChecker` method you write to the console variables of your `Program` class. They are actually different, so I think in your `StatusChecker` method you may want do the following:

```
public static void StatusChecker()
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Your health is " + Items.health);
    Console.WriteLine("Your energy is " + Items.energy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a variable here:

```
 public static string input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

So the next time you call your "Main" method it will use the value you typed in the first time your app executed. If you want it to ask each time you'll need to do something like this:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
     input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
     ...
 }
```

Another thing is that it can exit after the first call if you type in i.e. "status".
Issue number 3 is that this is not the "nice" way to write a program. The Main method is supposed to be executed when your app starts as it is the entry point (more on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)).